# Evaluate the defining Integral of the Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, trigonometry

I am trying to evaluate the integrals

$$ \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(x\sin t - nt)} \mathrm{d}t $$

and

$$ \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x\sin t} \mathrm{d}t $$

which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), should evaluate to $J_n(x)$ and $J_0(x)$, where $J_n(x)$ is the $n$-th order Bessel function of the first kind. However, when using `Integrate`, these two integrals are returned unevaluated.

Originally, I was trying to evaluate a more complicated expression similar to

$$ \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x(\sin (t+b+c)-\sin (b))} \mathrm{d}t $$

which can first be simplified using

$$ \sin(x+b)-\sin(b) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos\left(b + \frac{x}{2}\right) $$

and then rewritten to the form required for using the definition of the Bessel functions above by using the periodicity of $\cos$ and the fact that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are shifted relative to each other.

How can I calculate this integral using *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a rule-based, term-rewriting system, `Mathematica` transforms an input expression using a set of rules yielding an output expression. The integrals we consider can be evaluated if we add appropriate assumptions to `Integrate`. Symbols `x` and `n` can be whatever unless we restrict them somehow. 
First, we can see **what happens if `n` and `x` are prescribed**, e.g.

```
1/(2 π) Integrate[Exp[I (8 I Sin[t] - 6 t)], {t, -π, π}]
```

> ```
> 1/128 (-476 BesselI[0, 8] + 495 BesselI[1, 8])
> ```

According to  mathematical definitions it is `BesselJ[6, 8 I]`, and in fact we can check this equality with `FullSimplify`, even though when `FullSimplify` acts on one expression, it  is not transformed to the other one. I guess that the system might return quickly that

```
1/(2 π) Integrate[Exp[I ((2 + 3 I) Sin[t] - 2 t)], {t, -π, π}]
```

is simply `BesselJ[2, 2 + 3 I]` however **it does not work this way** but taking more than 15 minutes its evaluation is not concluded, although **we can check immediately** that the **both expressions are numerically equal**. This is a significant omission of the symbolic capabilities of the system.

However it appears that assuming  `x` as real we can go further by checking this integrals for integer `n`:

```
tb = Table[ 1/(2 π)Integrate[Exp[I (x Sin[t] - n t)], {t, -π, π},
             Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals], {n, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
>  {BesselJ[0, Abs[x]], BesselJ[1, x], BesselJ[2, Abs[x]], BesselJ[3, x],
>   (x (-24 + x^2) BesselJ[0, x] - 8 (-6 + x^2) BesselJ[1, x])/x^3,
>   (x (-48 + x^2) BesselJ[1, x] - 12 (-16 + x^2) BesselJ[2, x])/x^3}
> ```

and as we could expect

```
FullSimplify[{tb[[5]] == BesselJ[4, x], tb[[6]] == BesselJ[5, x]}]
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Such an integral cannot be evaluated for a general integer `n`,  e.g. this remains unevaluated

```
1/(2 π) Integrate[ Exp[I (x Sin[t] - n t)], {t, -π, π}, 
                    Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals && 0 <= n <= 5 && n ∈ Integers]
```

This clearly demonstrates that symbolic functionality behind `BesselJ` and related functions can be improved and why one might encounter some problems with evaluating our integrals.

**Edit**

The integral $\; \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x(\sin (t+b+c)-\sin (b))} \mathrm{d}t \;$ can be computed as suggested above, i.e.

```
Integrate[ Exp[I (x Sin[t + b + c] - Sin[b])], {t, -π, π}, 
           Assumptions -> (x | b | c) ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> 2 E^(-I Sin[b]) π BesselJ[0, Abs[x]]
> ```

The result doesn't depend on `c` (what is not surprising), we plot it for `b == 0`, with roots of $J_0(x)$ represented by `BesselJZero[0, k]`:

```
Plot[ 2π BesselJ[0, Abs[x]], {x, -16, 16}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Darker @ Cyan, Thickness[0.008]}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.016], Point[ Flatten[
        Table[{{BesselJZero[0, k], 0}, {-BesselJZero[0, k], 0}}, {k, 5}],
                                                        1]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Artes has already answered your question, so let me just add a note.

In fact, the integral

$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp\left(i(x\sin t - nt)\right) \mathrm{d}t$$

is only equal to the Bessel function $2\pi \operatorname{\mathit J}_n(x)$ **for integer $n$** (an assumption you neglected to mention in the OP). For arbitrary $n$, the integral is equal to $2\pi \operatorname{\mathbf J}_n(x)$, where $\operatorname{\mathbf J}_n(x)$ is the [Anger function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngerFunction.html), which is built into *Mathematica* as `AngerJ[n, x]`, and does degenerate into the Bessel function of the first kind for integral $n$.

For instance,

```
With[{n = 4/3, x = 11/5},
     {NIntegrate[Exp[I (x Sin[t] - n t)], {t, -π, π}, WorkingPrecision -> 25],
      N[2 π AngerJ[n, x], 25]} // Chop]
   {2.927772818442791700473353, 2.927772818442791700473353}

AngerJ[5, x]
   BesselJ[5, x]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Assuming[Element[x,Reals],Integrate[E^(I x Sin[t]),{t,-Pi,Pi}]]
```

which returns

```
2 Pi BesselJ[0,Abs[x]]
```

and

```
Assuming[Element[x,Reals]&&n==2,Integrate[E^(I(x Sin[t]-n t)),{t,-Pi,Pi}]]
```

which returns

```
2 Pi BesselJ[2,Abs[x]]
```

`Assuming` other small plausible values for n also finds your integral, `Assuming` x>0 will also work and eliminates the `Abs` in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica can do some integrals of this sort e.g.

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, Integrate[Exp[I x Sin[t]], {t, -Pi, Pi}]]
(* 2 π BesselJ[0, Abs[x]] *)
```

You no doubt recognise some of your expressions as Fourier Coefficients.  Mathematica can compute some of these, e.g.

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, FullSimplify[
  Table[FourierCoefficient[Exp[I x Sin[t]], t, n], {n, 0, 5}]]]

(* {BesselJ[0, x], BesselJ[1, x], BesselJ[2, x], BesselJ[3, x], (
 x (-24 + x^2) BesselJ[0, x] - 8 (-6 + x^2) BesselJ[1, x])/x^3, (
 x (-48 + x^2) BesselJ[1, x] - 12 (-16 + x^2) BesselJ[2, x])/x^3} *)
```

and can recognise that these are equivalent to the expressions you expect

```
FullSimplify[Thread[% == Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 0, 5}]]]
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```