# Why is this integrand not integrating to a Bessel function?

Tags: special-functions, assumptions, calculus-and-analysis

I know from the identities of [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) that the following is true:
$$
J_{m}\left( x \right) = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 \ \pi \ i^{m} } \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \ d\phi \ e^{i \left( x \cos{\phi} \ - \ m \ \phi \right)} \tag{0}
$$

However, when I try to integrate the following, Mathematica doesn't actually integrate the result.  It just spits back the input.

```
Assuming[Element[k, Reals] && Element[m, Integers], Integrate[Exp[I (m x + k Cos[x])],{x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Should I allow `m` to be more general, i.e., any numeric value (not necessarily fond of fractional Bessel function indices) or am I missing some other assumption that is preventing Mathematica from giving the proper result?

(I doubt this matters but for completeness, I have v12.1.1.0 and am using a Macbook Pro laptop.)

Note the linked question [Evaluate the defining Integral of the Bessel functions of the first kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216335/19732) has several answers that kind of answer my question, but I am curious why the above does not actually integrate.  That is, I specify the regions of validity clearly and arguments so Mathematica should recognize that the input is the integral form of the Bessel function.  I want to know why it's not evaluating, not just that it won't or how to make it work by explicitly specifying the Bessel function index `m` using something like `Table`.

Comment: Integrate[Exp[I (-x + m Cos[x])], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] returns a Bessel function.

Comment: @bills - That seems odd...  Is `m` the index of the resulting Bessel function?

Comment: @Artes - Kind of but not really so much as announce there is an issue.  That is, your answer clearly points out that with a general index of the Bessel function, the Integrate function won't symbolically integrate so we need to prescribe one.  My question isn't asking whether it will do this but why it won't?  Perhaps I need to rephrase things to be more clear?