# Why does Integrate not evaluate the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am following a caluclation in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates) paper, equation (7). There, it is stated that the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi e^{-ik_rr\cos(v_{\phi}-\phi)}=J_0(k_rr)$$results in the zeroth-order Bessel function. Why, then, does Mathematica not provide the same result?

```
Assuming[r \[Element] Reals && vr \[Element] Reals && v\[Phi] \[Element] Reals
 , Integrate[E^(-I r Subscript[v, r] Cos[v\[Phi] - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], 0, 
    2 \[Pi]}] // FullSimplify]
```

As an output, I simply get the integral in LateX form as if I would have written it down by hand.

Edit: Even weirder, if I leave out the $v_{\phi}$ in the integrand, I get the result, even though both should be the same as they are related by a simple change of variables: $v_{\phi} - \phi = \alpha$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate the defining Integral of the Bessel functions of the first kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216335/evaluate-the-defining-integral-of-the-bessel-functions-of-the-first-kind)

Comment: @Artes That indeed answers the first part, but not why Mathematica gives different results as I described in the edit

Comment: The accepted answer therein discusses related issues in details. If an expression is not evaluated it doesn't mean that the result is different. The system leaves a space for improvement though.

Comment: @Artes So what I get from the accepted answer there is that one might provide additional assumptions to the ```Ìntegrate``` function, e.g. input is real, integer-based, etc. However, for me, the expression still doesn't get calculated and stays purely symbolic

Comment: Although it doesn't change the outcome, note that in the integrand you used `Subscript[v, r]` whereas in the assumptions you used `vr`. These should be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@Artes' answer begins](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216339/4999), "As a rule-based, term-rewriting system...." Mathematica has a missing rule here, it seems.

If we reduce the number of parameters via substitution, which can be done without losing the original integral, Mathematica succeeds.  (Here I used the periodicity of cosine to translate the interval.)

```
Integrate[E^(-I rr Cos[-tt]), {tt, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> rr ∈ Reals] /. {rr -> r*Subscript[v, r]}
(*  2 π BesselJ[0, Abs[r Subscript[v, r]]]  *)
```

Not translating the interval fails (an appropriate rule seems to be missing):

```
Integrate[E^(-I rr Cos[-tt]), {tt, 0 - vϕ, 2 π - vϕ}, 
 Assumptions -> rr ∈ Reals && vϕ ∈ Reals]
(* ... input returned ... *)
```

A success:

```
Integrate[E^(-I rr Cos[-tt]), {tt, 0 - Pi/2, 2 π - Pi/2}, 
 Assumptions -> rr ∈ Reals]
(*  2 π BesselJ[0, Abs[rr]]  *)
```

More failures. One might or might not excuse the interval that depended on the parameter `vϕ`, but given the success with translation by `Pi/2`, I wonder at the failures with translation by other values.

```
Integrate[E^(-I rr Cos[-tt]), {tt, 0 - 1, 2 π - 1}, 
 Assumptions -> rr ∈ Reals]

Integrate[E^(-I rr Cos[-tt]), {tt, 0 - Pi/3, 2 π - Pi/3}, 
 Assumptions -> rr ∈ Reals]
```

Aside & caveat: Note that symbolically, `r` and `Subscript[v, r]`, which has the form `f[v, r]`, both depend on `r` as expressions.  This is probably not what was meant.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your last sentence: Does that mean that Mathematica interprets ```Subscript[v, r]``` as depending on ```r``` and not just as another declared variable like, e.g., ```z```?

Comment: @LionCereals Usually, yes. For instance `Solve[r == Subscript[v, r], r]`, `Integrate[Subscript[v, r], r]` and `D[Subscript[v, r]^2, r]` -- and compare with `vr`. I thought there was an instance `Subscript` was treated as not depending on its arguments, but I don't recall the circumstances.