# Strange result simplifying higher order BesselJ

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, integral-transforms

Consider the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 Z_n^m(r)\ J_m(\rho r) r dr$$.

The solution of this should contain a single Bessel function:
$$(-1)^{(m-n)/2}\ J_{n+1} (\rho)/\rho$$ (see https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/885409)

However, when performing this integral using Mathematica using the following code (substituting 5 for n and 1 for m):

```
FullSimplify[
Assuming[rho > 0 && r > 0 && phi \[Element] Reals && q \[Element] Reals, 
Integrate[ZernikeR[5, 1, r] r BesselJ[1, r rho], {r, 0, 1}]]]
```

The result is:

```
(rho (-80 + rho^2) BesselJ[2, rho] - 
 16 (-30 + rho^2) BesselJ[3, rho])/rho^4
```

Plotting this alongside $J_6(\rho)/\rho$ proves these two expressions are in fact identical. This is also true for other similar integrals involving higher order (n>4) Bessel functions. How can I get FullSimplify to simplify these types of expressions into a single Bessel function?

EDIT: Mathematica can even verify the truth of this statement using FullSimplify:

```
FullSimplify[(rho (-80 + rho^2) BesselJ[2, rho] - 
     16 (-30 + rho^2) BesselJ[3, rho])/rho^4 == BesselJ[6, rho]/rho]
```

yields `True`

Comment: Interesting perhaps: `LeafCount[(
 rho (-80 + rho^2) BesselJ[2, rho] - 
  16 (-30 + rho^2) BesselJ[3, rho])/rho^4]` is 25 but `LeafCount[BesselJ[6, rho]/rho]` is 7!

Comment: @I. C. Lin I think that the numerics kicks in as soon as you call the `Plot` command. Not sure who downvoted without comments though, that was not me

Comment: This is closely related: [Evaluate the defining Integral of the Bessel functions of the first kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216335/evaluate-the-defining-integral-of-the-bessel-functions-of-the-first-kind/216339#216339) or perhaps even a duplicate.

Comment: Mathematica does not always provide an answer in its simplest form.  So, applying `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to results that seem unduly complicated often is desirable.

Comment: @Artes, that question does seem to describe the same problem in your answer, but I do not see a solution for how to get FullSimplify to reduce the expression into a single term BesselJ, which is what I'm seeking. Maybe using TransformationFunctions as an argument to FullSimplify could do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's evident, that recursion formulas for series of special function are not integrated yet in FullSimplify or FunctionExpand.

The relevant formula here is the fundamental relation
$$Z_n(x)=\frac{ 2(n-1)}{x} \  Z_{n-1}(x) -Z_{n-2}(x)$$
for all kinds of Bessel functions.

Comment: Is there a way to provide FullSimplify this identity to get it to reduce Bessels?

Comment: According to the docs for BesselJ, FullSimplify can simplify Bessel-containing expressions: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJ.html.

I'm admittedly not familiar with Mathematica enough to know how it performs simplifications, but it does seem to have some knowledge about this and other relations (see latest edit)